# Assign multiple dataset as one variable

Tags: python

I am extracting multiple dataset into one csv file.

```
data =  Dataset(r'C:/path/2011.daily_rain.nc', 'r')
```

I successfully assigned one dataset but i still have ten more to work with in the same way. Are there any methods or functions can allow me to assign or combine multiple dataset as one variable?

Comment: I dont really understand what you want. It's not crystal clear. Can you provide sample output ?

Comment: Are you trying to read in multiple files and combine them into one dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've described, it sounds like you want to perform the same task on each set of data. If that is the case, then consider using storing your dataset paths in an array, then using a [for .. in loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) to iterate through each path.

Consider the following sample code:

```py
dataset_paths = [
    "C:/path/some_data_file-0.nc",
    "C:/path/some_data_file-1.nc",
    "C:/path/some_data_file-2.nc",
    "C:/path/some_data_file-3.nc",
    # ... and the rest of your dataset file paths
]

for path in dataset_paths:
    data = Dataset(path, 'r')
    # Code that uses the data here
```

Everything in the `for .. in` block will be run for each path defined in the `dataset_paths` array. This will allow you to work with each dataset in the same way.